# Правильное использование Row_Number()

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день!
В этом запросе я отфильтровал дубликаты
У меня есть запрос(на примере):

```
with tmp as(
Select 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY dp.global_id Order BY dp.global_id) AS RN,
od.name as dept, dp.global_id, null as premium
FROM Folders f
inner join DOCS d on d.FOLDERS_ID = f.id
left join docs_policy dp on dp.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
Left join ogpo_application oa on oa.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
left join ogpo_dept od on od.id = oa.dept_id

UNION ALL

SELECT null as RN, null as global_id, pr.InsPremia as premium
FROM
[1cGate_Restored].[dbo].[Deals] dea
Left Join [1cGate_Restored].[dbo].[Products] pr ON pr.DealID = dea.ID
)
Select * From tmp
Where RN = 1
```

Этот запрос работает, но я должен сделать это через иерархию.
Теперь я добавил иерархию:

```
with tmp as(
    with t(id1,parent_id1,obj_type1,obj_id1,dept_name1, dept_id1) as
    (код иерархии.......)

    Select 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY dp.global_id Order BY dp.global_id) AS RN, t.dept_name1 as dept,
    dp.global_id, null as premium
    FROM Folders f
    inner join DOCS d on d.FOLDERS_ID = f.id
    left join docs_policy dp on dp.docs_id = d.DOCS_ID
    left join t on t.obj_id1 = od.id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT null as RN, null as dept, null as global_id, pr.InsPremia as premium
    FROM
    [1cGate_Restored].[dbo].[Deals] dea
    Left Join [1cGate_Restored].[dbo].[Products] pr ON pr.DealID = dea.ID
    )
    Select * From tmp
    Where RN = 1
```

Но здесь выдает ошибку `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'`
Вопрос: как в случаи двух with добавить row_number, первый запрос работал, но я добавил иерархию по `dept`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перечисляйте cte в порядке использования через запятую:

```
with t(id1,parent_id1,obj_type1,obj_id1,dept_name1, dept_id1) as (код иерархии.......),
tmp as (ваш код, использующий t)
```